# How to execute scalar query on an IMobileServiceSyncTable?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'm moving my app over from Sqlite-Net to Azure Mobile Services and I'm adding offline sync capabilities.

I'm unsure how to execute arbitrary queries. This is what I have for Sqlite-Net:

`var newestDate = await this.connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<DateTime> ("SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) FROM SupplyData");`

How can I run this query against my `IMobileServiceSyncTable` instance?
There is a `CreateQuery()` method but it does not take any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't use LINQ?

```
// This query filters out completed TodoItems and items without a timestamp.
List<TodoItem> items = await todoTable
   .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Complete == false)
   .ToListAsync();
```

Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#filtering

The alternate to this is to call a custom API.  In ASP.NET backends, this is just a WebAPI that uses the underlying Entity Framework stuff.  See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-define-a-custom-api-controller  For Node.js backends (or Easy Tables / Easy API), see the following sample code:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/tree/master/samples/custom-api-sql-stmt

Comment: Because LINQ extensions have no support for aggregate functions like SQL's `MAX()`. Even if I can work around it with LINQ I would still like to know how to execute arbitrary SQL queries.

Comment: Great point.  You get to write a custom API for random SQL.  I'll update my answer with a pointer to a sample

Comment: If you want to execute arbitrary SQL queries on the local store (i.e., items that have been locally downloaded), you can run the statements by using the MobileServiceSQLiteStore and calling the [ReadAsync method](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore/MobileServiceSQLiteStore.cs#L100). However, you are limited the SQL that is supported by SQLite.